# Converting KMZ-file to KML

Tags: convert, kml, kmz

Is there an easy way (like unzip) to convert a KMZ-file to KML?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes.

Inside the `.kmz` is a file called `doc.kml`, see [wikipedia | Keyhole Markup Language | Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language#Structure)

You can use 7-zip to open the KMZ archive.

---

**References:**

- [KMZ Files | Recommended Directory Structure](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives#recommended-directory-structure)

Answer (score 34):

or change the file extension to .zip under windows to open with winzip.

In unix/linux/osx:

```
cp myfile.kmz myfile.zip
unzip myfile.zip
cp doc.xml myfile.kml
```

Comment: You can just unzip the kmz file directly, Unix doesn't care about file extensions.

Comment: @HeyOverThere most Unix utilities don't care, but some, such as gunzip are picky about extensions.

Comment: The rename file extension technique works like a charm in Windows 7.

Answer (score 17):

No need for a third party tool. Change the extension to .zip, open and extract the file you want.

Comment: +1 If you are using 7zip, you do not even need to add a ".zip" extension.

Answer (score 10):

This is most likely no practical solution, but you can import your kmz-file in google earth (open) and export it (rightlick -> save) it as kml.
Somehere out there is certainly a easy tool for conversion/extraction.

Comment: good idea Google Earth choked on a 57MB file. I guess that is a different problem.

Comment: hui, then maybe you should first extract the doc.kml file as mentioned by HeyOverThere. On this link you will find further informations about the kmz file format: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives

Comment: @Abe solid state memory is the way to go. I have 16GB of RAM too, thats definitely helpful too.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and changed the extension from KMZ to ZIP. Clicking the ZIP file lead me to the KML file, then made the import from both QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop work.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to convert KMZ to KML within few seconds using this online [KMZ to KML Converter](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/kmz-to-kml)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python software for it. It's a 2-step task, where the first one shows unzipping the .kmz file, the second one replicating the name of the .kml file

https://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/kmz-to-kml-quick-conversion-with-python/